# Java Regex to split words, punctuation, spaces, new lines but keep contractions?

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a long string into an array of its contents by word using a regex. Right now I'm using (?<=\b) but the problem is that it splits up words that are contractions (such as you're fixin', things like that). I need a regex that would make punctuation its own element except in cases as above, along with tabs, spaces, new lines being their own elements as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out StringTokenizer. You can specify multiple delimiters (2nd parameter) and you can specify to whether to return such delimiters (3rd parameter set to true to return space, newline, tab, etc). If you don't want the space, tab, newline returned as tokens, set to false (or better yet, don't have a 3rd parameter).

```
String testString = "this isn't\nright\t 'cause it ain't true";
StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(testString," \n\t\r",true);
while (s.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println("'" + s.nextToken() + "'");
}
```

Outputs:

```
'this'
' '
'isn't'
'
'
'right'
'   '
' '
''cause'
' '
'it'
' '
'ain't'
' '
'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to look at definition of `\b` ("word boundary") and then \w ("word") and redefine a `'` as part of a word.  Something like this, although it depends if you need the delimiters too or if you can let the regex swallow them.

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      String test = "Don't fear the reaper.";
      String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9']";
      System.out.println( Arrays.toString( test.split( regex ) ) );
   }
```

Output:

```
run:
[Don't, fear, the, reaper]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```